# Some Reducers not fired although action did

Tags: angular, action, ngrx, reduce

I use ngrx 12 and am building the registration process.

At authActions.registerAction step the reducer corresponding does fire, everything good, but after that, only the action registerSuccessAction is fired but the corresponding reducer doesn't. How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help.

**app.module.ts**

```
  StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
```

**index.ts**

```
import { ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

import { authReducer, AuthState } from './auth.reducer';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export interface AppState {
  auth: AuthState;
}

export const rootReducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  auth: authReducer,
};
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = !environment.production
  ? []
  : [];
```

**auth.reducer:**

```
const _authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(
    authActions.registerAction,
    (state): AuthState => ({
      ...state,
      isSubmitting: true,
      validationErrors: null,
    })
  ),
  on(
    authActions.registerSuccessAction,
    (state, action): AuthState => ({
      ...state,
      isSubmitting: false,
      isLoggedIn: true,
      isSuccessfulRegistration: true,
      currentUser: action.currentUser,
    })
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please show how you dispatch the actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works now. i just didn't pass the data correctly.